# ObservableArray does not reflect its value outside of function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, reference, scope

In [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/VGqvx/) you can see that I initiate empty `observableArray([])` and then update it after 2 seconds, and click on buttons you can see that direct reference gives me empty array and function that calls within object gets the actual value.

**Why is it behaving like that? How can I get a direct reference outside?**

Note: I need to use `ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.orig))` because I want to copy data so it does not link to the original array.

Code:

```
var vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.orig = ko.observableArray([{
        somevalue: ko.observable("testst")
    }]);

    self.diff = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.init = function() {
        self.diff = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.orig));
    }

    setTimeout(self.init,2000);

    return {
        check: function() { alert(self.diff());console.log(self.diff());},
        diff: self.diff
    }
}
```

### Update

It seems the problem was that I needed to change this

`self.diff = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.orig));`

to this

`ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.orig),{},self.diff);`

Comment: Exactly, here's more about [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue.

You are not setting the value of the KO array self.diff. You are actually just setting it equal to it and when you do that, it is no longer the same KO observable array you initialized.

Additionally, as far as I know, the ko.toJS creates a plain JS copy so you don't need the ko.mapping.fromJS call.

```
//What you are doing
self.diff = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.orig));

//What you need to do
self.diff(ko.toJS(self.orig));
```

Updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VGqvx/6/

Comment: I actually need to use mapping because of how I map values to array, but your answer covers the main problem.